# How to set App Icon in ios7

Tags: ios7, icons, launch

I created an universal application in xcode 5.how can I set App Icons and launch images from general tab?

[image]

On clicking the arrow button near the  app icons, 
[image]

How to set AppIcon here?Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: just take your image with suitable size and drop it on selected area)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just need to drag & drop the images in the right sizes. The correct sizes are indicated by below the descriptions (e.g. 29pt) and the 2x or 1x on top:

29pt 2x = 58px,
40pt 2x = 80px,
29pt 1x = 29px,
...

Comment: 0.75pt = 1px.. by the way.

Comment: @filou [Apple themselves](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html) state that e.g. 60pt 2x = 120px...

Answer (score 0):

Also, the file type must be PNG.  I've been stuck on that one before!